# Android appication is not running when mainout.xml created

Tags: android, mobile-application

in my Android application the file with name "mainout.xml" is creating, where ever this file created the application is not running.

any one know how to solve this problem??

Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to help you. Who/What is creating the mainout.xml file? Is it used by your program? How? There may be an error in your XML file causing the program not to compile. Provide more detail!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common bug when you make Eclipse run your application and you have the focus on an xml file. Just delete the out.xml file, put your focus on a java class, and build as usual.
If you still have an error, do a project clean. And it should  be fine.

Comment: That's a good question, but i'm not an android engineer, so this time, I can't answer...